# Send Email Opens in New App

Tags: ios, email, cordova

I am creating an Apache-Cordova/Phonegap App, that the user click on a button and the send email screen displays.

The problems is that it opens in the iPhone's Mail app, instead of popping up on top of the WebView. When the user clicks "Cancel," they remain in the Mail app, and do not return to my app.

Here is the HTML that is launching the email:

```
<a href="mailto:EMAIL@ADDRESS.COM?subject=Inquiry About Boston Landmarks" data-transition="slide"><h1>App Support</h1></a>
```

Any ideas?

**Update: Here is what I am expecting, but not getting. (demo from Safari)
[image: safari email]**

Answer (score 0):

mailto: is a url scheme to open the mail app, and what you are describing is exactly what it is supposed to do. To open a mail window in your app - you actually need to code some objective C and use the MFMailComposeViewController Class. Phonegap would allow you to do this.

Comment: The confusing thing is that in Mobile Safari, the same syntax loads a mail message without opening the mail app. I have added an image to the question describing this result.

Comment: URL schemes are supposed to open the apps outside your app as per Apple documentation. Mobile Safari is an app by itself, it is not the exactly the same as the facility (although I assumed that codes / common routines are actually shared) that you invoke when using Cordova,

Comment: Do you know of a Cordova plugin that can open a blank email within the app?

Comment: No - I looked into Cordova and I know that you can hook an  Objective C class into it, but I typically code using Objective C so I am not very knowledgeable about 3rd party plugins.